# ASP.NET how to check if client is Mac

Tags: asp.net

Seems like there are several ways to do this. I've found to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent`, `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")`, `Request.Browser.Platform`. Not sure which one is a more correct way to detect the OS version. Also, how do I get a list of the OS version string that client browser may send to web server. With that string, so I can filter it out in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get operating system version asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561528/how-to-get-operating-system-version-asp-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`Request.UserAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent.aspx).

[User agent list](http://www.user-agents.org/index.shtml)